# How can I design an extended menu bar in Angular, ensuring that overflowing menu entries are neatly organized within a sub-menu?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I want to create an angular menu that have lot of entire, and I want the entry that overflow the parent container to be stored inside a sub menu at the end of the bar that I have call "Next".

At the end, I want something that look like that :

[image: Exemple of overflow end by btn]

The problem is that the overflow persists, and the "next" button doesn't immediately follow the last link. Also the list of overflow menu (taht apear on next button) don't seams to be in real time.

And also I'm not sure if I use the best method to do this.

To do this I have used a reize observer and two view child one for the parent container and one for the menu container to know where it overflow.

And I use the index of the first item outside to slice my first array in another observable that combine the two observable.

here is the code :

```js
 ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // create rxjs resize observable
    resizeObservable(this.navBar.nativeElement)
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        map(() => {
          const navBar = this.navBar.nativeElement;
          const parent = this.navList.nativeElement;
          const children: HTMLDivElement[] = Array.from(
            parent.children
          ) as HTMLDivElement[];
          const lastIndex = this.lastVisibleIndex$.value;
          let minOutside: number = -1;
          children.forEach((child, index) => {
            // check if child is outside the parrent
            if (isOutsideParent(child, navBar)) {
              minOutside = minOutside === -1 ? index : minOutside;
              child.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            } else {
              child.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
          });
          return minOutside === -1 ? lastIndex : minOutside;
        }),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe(this.lastVisibleIndex$);
  }
```

and here is the code for the observable that slice my array of tbd to start at the first item to be hidden :

```js
    const tbdArray: Tbd[] = Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, index) => ({
      identifiant: `ID_${index + 1}`,
      name: `Name_${index + 1}`,
    }));
    this.tbds$ = of(tbdArray);

    this.tbdsOverflow$ = combineLatest({
      lastVisibleIndex: this.lastVisibleIndex$,
      tbds: this.tbds$,
    }).pipe(
      map(({ tbds, lastVisibleIndex }) => {
        return tbds.filter((_, index) => index >= lastVisibleIndex);
      })
    );
```

Finally here is a stackblitz that contain the base reproducing of my menu issues :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-5sbobb?file=src%2Flong-bar%2Flong-bar.component.ts